# Is there a way to create an unlogged batch when using a Datastax Cassandra CSharp LINQ Batch?

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql3, datastax

I'm using the Batch class found in the `Cassandra.Data.Linq` namespace.  Not a `BatchStatement`.  The Batch class has a field for `batchType` (Counter, Logged, Unlogged).  However, I'm not seeing a way to set it to `Unlogged`.  Hoping I'm just overlooking it.

Comment: What version of the C# driver?

Comment: @AlexPopescu 2.0.0 beta 2, soon to upgrade to 2.0.2. (nuget version numbers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (2.5.2), there is no way to set `batchType` to `Unlogged`.

`_batchType` is a protected field and the only 2 classes extending the abstract `Batch` class do not expose any methods or properties allowing you to set the field.

https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Data/Linq/BatchV1.cs

https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Data/Linq/BatchV2.cs

Answer (score 2):

Since I just had the same question, in the current version (2.5) there is [SetBatchType](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/csharp/2.5/html/M_Cassandra_BatchStatement_SetBatchType.htm). Curiously this is a separate method as opposed to [BatchType](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/csharp/2.5/html/P_Cassandra_BatchStatement_BatchType.htm) having a Set as well as a Get accessor. Thus my code is

```
BatchStatement bs = new BatchStatement();
bs.SetBatchType(BatchType.Unlogged);
```

As a reminder there is a [warning](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword-40f00e35e23e) scattered throughout the documentation that batches should generally go to a single node which means calling [SetRoutingKey](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/csharp/2.5/html/M_Cassandra_BatchStatement_SetRoutingKey.htm) or [SetRoutingValues](http://www.datastax.com/drivers/csharp/2.5/html/M_Cassandra_BatchStatement_SetRoutingValues.htm) (composite partition key) is likely advisable.

Comment: Hmm, I'll check out the latest bits when I have a chance over the next couple days and see if anything was added to the Cassandra.Data.Linq.Batch class.  Note that in my question I did mention that I was interested in Cassandra.Data.Linq.Batch and NOT in Cassandra.BatchStatement

Comment: Whoops, yes you did. Show how optimistic I was being that this was the same problem. It doesn't look like Cassandara.Data.Linq has a public field for batchType?